# PyPDF4 not reading certain characters

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm compiling some data for a project and I've been using PyPDF4 to read this data from it's source PDF file, but I've been having trouble with certain characters not showing up correctly. Here's my code:

```
from PyPDF4 import PdfFileReader
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

# File name
pdf_path = "PV-9-2020-10-23-RCV_FR.pdf"

# Results storage
results = {}

# Start page
page = 5

# Lambda to assign votes
serify = lambda voters, vote: pd.Series({voter.strip(): vote for voter in voters})

with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as f:
    # Get PDF reader for PDF file f
    pdf = PdfFileReader(f)

    while page < pdf.numPages:
        # Get text of page in PDF
        text = pdf.getPage(page).extractText()

        proposal = text.split("\n+\n")[0].split("\n")[3]

        # Collect all pages relevant pages
        while text.find("\n0\n") is -1:
            page += 1
            text += "\n".join(pdf.getPage(page).extractText().split("\n")[3:])
        # Remove corrections
        text, corrections = text.split("CORRECCIONES")
        
        # Grab relevant text !!! This is where the missing characters show up.
        text = "\n, ".join([n[:n.rindex("\n")] for n in text.split("\n:")])
        for_list = "".join(text[text.index("\n+\n")+3:text.index("\n-\n")].split("\n")[:-1]).split(", ")
        nay_list = "".join(text[text.index("\n-\n")+3:text.index("\n0\n")].split("\n")[:-1]).split(", ")
        abs_list = "".join(text[text.index("\n0\n")+3:].split("\n")[:-1]).split(", ")
        # Store data in results
        results.update({proposal: dict(pd.concat([serify(for_list, 1), serify(nay_list, -1), serify(abs_list, 0)]).items())})
        page += 1
        print(page)
results = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

The characters I'm having difficulty don't show up in the text extracted using `extractText`. `Ždanoka` for instance becomes `"danoka`, `Štefanec` becomes `-tefanc`. It seems like most of the characters are Eastern European, which makes me think I need one of the latin decoders.

I've looked through some of PyPDF4's capabilities, it seems like it has plenty of relevant codecs, including `latin1`. I've attempted decoding the file using different functions from the `PyPDF4.generic.codecs` module, and either the characters don't show still, or the code throws an error at an unrecognised byte.

I haven't yet attempted using multiple codecs on different bytes from the same file, that seems like it would take some time. Am I missing something in my code that can easily fix this? Or is it more likely I *will* have to tailor fit a solution using PyPDF4's functions?

Comment: A quick test: if you open the PDF with Acrobat Reader, can you copy this text correctly?

Comment: I copied the text correctly, yes. I believe the problem is that PyPDF4 does not actually have latin2, which is apparently what is needed.

I took the following test which I tried after your suggestion:

```
try:
    print("Ždanoka".encode("latin1").decode("latin1"))
except:
    print("broke")
try:
    print("Ždanoka".encode("latin2").decode("latin2"))
except:
    print("broke")
```

First one breaks, second doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pypdf`](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) instead of PyPDF2/PyPDF3/PyPDF4. You will need to [apply the migrations](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/migration-1-to-2.html).

pypdf has received a lot of updates in December 2022. Especially the text extraction.

To give you a minimal full [example for text extraction](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-text.html):

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")

for page in reader.pages:
    print(page.extract_text())
```